# Is it possible to develop for Windows 8.1 Desktop and Store App in the same solution?

Tags: c#, windows, desktop, visual-studio-2013

I'm using [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986965.aspx) to try to develop a Windows App.
I have a solution for a Desktop WinForm project that contains a number of class library projects and other tool WinForm projects.  I'd like to build the same program, but with the new Windows 8 App interface for easier touch controls.  But the two versions of Visual Studio don't seem to want to work together.

So, ultimately:
Is there a way to develop both a WinForm and Windows Store App in the same solution with VS Express 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, not with the Express editions.  With the paid SKUs of Visual Studio, you can have a single solution with both products.

The Express Editions have separate products for Desktop and Windows Store development (Express 2013 for Windows and Express 2013 for Windows Desktop), and you'll need to use the appropriate product within each edition.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I guess I'll just continue to ignore Windows Store App development if I can't utilize existing code.

Comment: @LouisIngenthron You can make a library (look at portable libraries) and share it across both - they just can't be in one solution.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking into that now, but I don't see any option to create a Portable Class Library in VSE13... and no way to convert my existing class libraries.  The only docs I can find on the subject are for VSE12... and just found this: "The template is available only in Visual Studio 2012 Pro or greater versions."  So, I guess MS isn't interested in letting people reuse code across platforms unless they get paid this cycle.

Comment: @LouisIngenthron: it might be a bit painful, but you can manually maintain the two projects and [link the files](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSSharedFiles.aspx)

Comment: @Chris Yeah, that might be possible, but it's not worth the effort to link every single source file, forever.  Plus, that would be made even more painful with source control, right?  It's really quite ridiculous how disincentivized Microsoft has made this for existing developers; it's such a 180 from the attitude that brought us the express editions to begin with.

Comment: @LouisIngenthron: Source control won't be too bad; you wouldn't be _copying_ the files, only linking them. So the second project will only have its csproj and folder structure without the files. I agree, it's a bit of a pain, but doable for a relatively small project. Regarding Express, it can do _a lot_ of things, and IMO is a pretty damn good offering for _free_ and Professional isn't that expensive for "existing developers". Also, this limitation has existed since Express started in 2005. IMO the _spirit_ of Express has been fairly consistent. If anything they've improved over the years.

Comment: @LouisIngenthron: On second thought, I suppose the underlying limitation has been exacerbated by the fact that Express can now support many more platforms than it did in 2005. Back then it was just Winforms/Console or ASP.NET, so no problem. But now Microsoft has added so many more platforms into the mix and the concept of code sharing and multi-platform development is much more common than what it once was. So while Express functions the same way as it always has, it just has too many bases to cover. Maybe that's why they reduced the cost for Professional in general from what it used to be.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I agree that in general the value is fantastic for free on the express version.  My gripe is that, as I understand it, the point of the express versions was to get people using and developing for Microsoft products; Windows, Xbox, WinPhone, etc.  And I love the app store for Win8, unlike many.  So it baffles me that Microsoft would do anything to make app development harder.  If it was all integrated, it would push developers to use the new non-desktop format.  But, as is, it's more trouble than it's worth (or comes with a $500 price tag).